# C# override instance method

Tags: c#, .net

So basically I have an object that takes instances and adds them to a list. Each instance uses virtual methods, which I need to override once the instance is created. How would I go about overriding methods of an instance?

Comment: You don't override methods of an _instance_, you override methods of a _class_.  If you need to override methods, define child classes with the overridden methods and create instances of those child classes.

Comment: Perhaps override isn't the best choice of words from the OP, but what they want to do is a valid idea, essentially they want to be able to change functionality at runtime, which as @JustinNiessner suggests, can be done quite nicely using delegates.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. You can only override a method when defining a class.

The best option is instead to use an appropriate `Func` delegate as a placeholder and allow the caller to supply the implementation that way:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Func<string> Method { get; set; }

    public void PrintSomething()
    {
        if(Method != null) Console.WriteLine(Method());
    }
}

// Elsewhere in your application

var instance = new SomeClass();
instance.Method = () => "Hello World!";
instance.PrintSomething(); // Prints "Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

C# is static once the object is created you cannot change the behavior of the object. you can subclass a superclass using inhertance, but this is done at designtime, not runtime.

```
class foo
{
    public virtual void dosomething()
    {
         console.writeline("this is foo");
    }
}

class bar : foo
{
    public override void dosomething()
    {
         console.writeline("this is bar");
    }
}

var list = new Foo[]{new foo(), new bar()};
```

There is also the concept of AOP - aspect oriented programming. This is where you can begin to inject behavior at runtime. there are 2 frameworks that I'm aware of that do this

1. Castle Dynamic Proxy
2. Spring.Net

Comment: I've considered this, however I don't know how many object types will be defined.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible at runtime. You cannot change a class' behaviour once it has been instantiated. You could however look into creating a delegate method.

EDIT, just saw the first answer, go with that ;)